# How can I make a special file that executes code when read from

Tags: files, filesystems

Most files on a Linux system are normal files, i.e. they are saved on disk and reading from them just reads from a specified chunk of memory on the disk.  How can I make something that behaves like a file in terms of being able to read from it as one would a normal file, but is actually returning programmatically generated data instead?  As a concrete example, a file that downloads the current google.com and returns it, such that `cat ~/myspecialfile` would output the contents of google.com to stdout?

Comment: If I found such an artifact on my system I would consider it hostile and anything produced by its creator would be permanently blacklisted.

Comment: @ExUmbris: I recommend you never look at the contents of `/run` then, or else your software choices are going to become severely constrained.  :-) (That's for Ubuntu, at least: on other flavors check `/var/run`, `/var/tmp` or similar locations.)

Comment: OK, point taken, sometimes "files" backed by kernel modules are useful.  However, if I installed something expecting a file and found it unexpectely executing code when I tried to display it I'd be unhappy :-)

Comment: May we ask you **why** you need this?  Could be a XYProblem...

Comment: Contribute a kernel module, maybe?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the other answers have indicated, you can do part of what you've asked for using named pipes. For a complete solution, you'd have to develop some kind of [virtual filesystem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_file_system) that took the desired actions when a path on the virtual filesystem was accessed. There are a few approaches to doing this:

- Write a kernel-mode filesystem driver, like the [procfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs) driver.
- Write a user-mode filesystem implementation, using [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) for example.
- Write a program which provides an [NFS server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System) interface or another network filesystem protocol.
- Maybe a program that pretends to be a USB file-storage device or another piece of hardware.

Answer (score 7):

You can conceivably do something like this with a FIFO/named pipe:

```
$ mkfifo ~/myspecialfile
$ wget -q -O ~/myspecialfile google.com &
[2] 26186
$
```

`mkfifo` creates a named pipe called ~/myspecialfile.  `wget` then directs its output to that named pipe.  You can read (once) from that named pipe as if it were a regular file.  e.g. to get `wc` counts for that file:

```
$ wc ~/myspecialfile
      7     430   17738 /home/ubuntu/myspecialfile
[2]+  Done                    wget -q -O ~/myspecialfile google.com
$
```

Note that typically the writer (`wget` in this instance) will `open()` the pipe with the O_WRONLY flag.  This `open()` call will typically block until the reader (`wc` in this instance) opens the other end of the pipe with the O_RDONLY flag.  So here the `wget` process will be started immediately, but it will be doing nothing in the background until the reader (opens and) starts to read.  I have verified this behaviour with wireshark on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: This will run `wget` immediately, though, right? Not just when the file is read?

Comment: @WChargin Yes, that's right, but it will sit in the background doing nothing until the pipe is read from.  See my edit.

Answer (score 4):

You can make `myspecialfile` a named pipe. Then you can have a script running in the background that's in a loop writing the output of the program to the pipe:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkfifo ~/myspecialfile
while :; do
    run program here > ~/myspecialfile
done
```

There's a limitation to this. If two processes both open the file at the same time, they might each get only parts of the output.

A more elaborate way to do something that doesn't have this limitation would be to implement a FUSE filesystem. `~/myfyspecialfile` would be the mount point of the filesystem.